# <select> Initial value is showing undefined (React js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I want to show the option selected by the user in console in **Select** tag but as user select **test1** console show me **undefined** and when user select **test 2** then it show me previous selected value that is **test1** and so on.

**Component.jsx**

```js
<Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlSelect1">

  <Form.Label>Login as</Form.Label>
  <Form.Control as="select" defaultValue="test1" onChange={getOptionValue} >
  
    <option>test1</option>
    <option>test2</option>
    <option>test3</option>
    
  </Form.Control>
</Form.Group>
```

**useState**

```
const [getOption, setOption] = useState();
    const getOptionValue = (e) => {
        setOption(e.target.value);
        console.log(`here is selected option${getOption}`);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `setOption` will only take effect once the current function scope has ended and control has been given back to the react runtime. You

Here is a workaround if you really want to see the change right there:

```
const getOptionValue = (e) => {
   setOption(e.target.value);
   setTimeout(() => console.log(`here is selected option${getOption}`), 1);
}
```

The better solution would be to add that `console.log` statement right before the return statement of your render function (or functional react component).

Comment: I got it, there is no need to use useState here so e.target.value or e.value worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please don't forget to upvote and/or accept the answer